# add a local picture to imindq mind maps

Tags: productivity

almost all is in the title : imindq asks an url when attempting to add a picture to a node. 
I would like to add a local picture... 
I tried something like this :

> file:///sdcard/pictures/position_-2101364257.jpg

but it does not seem to work. 
thank you

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you got confused with the document option and image option. The one just below the + sign is for document which you ended up using. The third from the bottom (icon of a scenery) provides the image functionality. Even in there, you get to select only icons from a given set.

<sub>(Click image to enlarge)</sub>

[image: IMG:]