# Add local pictures to iMindQ mind maps for Android

Tags: files, url

Almost all is in the title: iMindQ asks an URL when attempting to add a picture to a node. I would like to add a local picture...

I tried something like this:

> ```
> file:///sdcard/pictures/position_-2101364257.jpg
> ```

but it does not seem to work.

Comment: This is a question for an Android site.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a detailed question about software use of a specific Android program.

Comment: ok, I will move

Comment: @lolveley you can delete this post. Your exact question has been answered here: https://android.stackexchange.com/q/181178/96277